# hgsubversion doesn't find python bindings

Tags: 11.10, svn, mercurial

I upgraded to 11.10 yesterday, and since then the hgsubversion extension of mercurial no longer find the python bindings.

```
abort: no compatible bindings available:

Subversion 1.5.0 or later required, but no bindings were found
Subvertpy 0.7.4 or later required, but not found

Please install either Subvertpy or the Subversion Python SWIG bindings!
```

However, both this packages are currently installed (version 1.6.12dfsg-4ubuntu5 for python-subversion and version 0.8.3-1 for python-subvertpy).

Initially I was using hgsubversion pulled from their mercurial repository, which I had to update following mercurial update, so I'm now at revision 836 (October 12th). As I saw there was now a package for hgsubversion in the repository (don't know when it has been added), I tried with that version as well, but to no avail.

So far, here's what I tried to fix the problem or help diagnose:

1. I reinstalled subversion, mercurial, python and both bindings package.
2. I noticed I had python 2.6 and python 2.7, so I removed python 2.6.
3. Forcing the use of Subvertpy with HGSUBVERSION_BINDINGS="Subvertpy": `abort: Subvertpy 0.7.4 or later required, but not found!`
4. Forcing the use of SWIG bindings with HGSUBVEERSION_BINDINGS="SWIG": `abort: Subversion 1.5.0 or later required, but no bindings were found!`
5. Tried using alternatively both the Ubuntu package version of hgsubversion (1.2.1-2.1) and the latest version pulled from hgsbuversion repository.

Does anyone know why would that happen and what should I have to do to fix it?

Thank you.

Edit: forgot a few version informations

```
python --version
Python 2.7.2+
```

package version: 2.7.2-5ubuntu1

```
hg version
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.9.1)
```

package version: 1.9.1-1ubuntu0.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the cause: it was coming from the line in my hgrc defining the use of the hgview extension.

After the upgrade, my old `hgview=` line to activate failed (it wouldn't find the extension), and I had replaced it with `hgext.hgview=/usr/share/pyshared/hgext/hgview.py` after having located it.

As there was no longer any hgview related error in the log afterwards, I didn't think much about it. However that was the cause of my hgsubversion not finding the bindings, though I still don't know why.

Thus, removing that line in my `.hgrc` file solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On HgSubversion wiki you can read :

> The easiest way to install hgsubversion is to just clone the
>   hgsubversion repository and then configure Mercurial to use it.
>   **Cloning the tip is recommended as it is much more stable than the latest tag 1.2.1 from march 2011.**

Clone the repository :

```
$ hg clone http://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion/ hgsubversion
```

All tests passed :

```
$ nosetests
Ran 493 tests in 1400.680s

OK
```

Check that HgSubversion is installed and properly activated :

```
$ hg version --svn
Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.9.1)
(see http://mercurial.selenic.com for more information)

Copyright (C) 2005-2011 Matt Mackall and others
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions. There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

hgsubversion: 3292ff0380f3
Subversion: 1.6.12
bindings: Subvertpy 0.8.3
```

Comment: Wasn't that. I was already using the latest revision from hgsubversion update October 12th), and had even tested again after updating to 1.3 to no avail. Finally found the cause though, which I added as an answer.